# Check which props are allowed for react child components

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to find out which props are allowed in React components when using `React.Children.map`. Here is an example:

```
{React.Children.map(props.children, c => React.cloneElement(c, extendedProps))}
```

The `extendedProps` can hold unknown props for the specific child, which leads to an [Unknown Prop Warning](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/unknown-prop.html).

Comment: something like that? http://jsbin.com/tujusi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Actually I hoped for a solution where I can access the `propTypes` defined for a component, not just the type of the component.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/rakenod/1/edit?html,js,output with propTypes checking